Is understanding nothing the answer to everything
Is the philosophy of nothing still in serious debate somehow/somewhere?. As a concept of the existence of "stuff". I always come quickly to the conclusion that because something is now existing and recognized then there must have always been something and nothing is not a possible state of existence. Is it way out of our (human) league to get an answer to this paradox? It has just dawned on me that I am probably contemplating the whole of Metaphysics.

Re. there must have always been something always existing... See Jaininsm. Also shunya in buddhism

See Nothingness.

All the early birds are out catching worms this morning. :-)

It is generally thought that not only space but time began with the Big Bang. In that sense, there was nothing, and it exploded, but it wasn't 'before' our universe. We only have evidence for cosmology a certain finite time after the supposed singularity, calculated by running the expansion of the universe backwards - and there are problems with the picture. Singularities are 'unphysical', for instance blackholes now are thought to a Planck-scale superfluid, not a singularity. There's also Inflation to explain, a period of extra fast expansion in the early universe, plus no one knows why the expansion of the universe now is accelerating - this is called the Dark Energy problem, and relates to Zero Point Energy which seems to suggest 'empty' space is very energy-dense.
There's still 'everything to play for' in grappling with these issues in physics, for instance Roger Penrose has proposed Conformal Cyclic Cosmology, a picture where everything in the universe decays to photons and linked to the fact photons don't experience time, the photon 'soup' is equivalent to a new Big Bang. Another picture is M-Theory, where our universe is the collision of surfaces moving within a higher dimensional space, where time is just part of the constraints of the 'surface' of pur universe, embedded in a larger space of all possible universes and initual  conditions conditions. It's difficult to grapple with the timeless parts of the story of our cosmos, and anyway physics is just one context for thinking about nothingness, leaving space for philosophical work on the topic.
How to think about 'nothing' is definitely a 'live' philosophical issue, eg whether as a formal substance or category, or only as a contrastive or absence (see the Hole Argument on Wikipedia, or Holes on SEP). You might like to look through the IEP article on the Metaphysics of Nothing, or I really recommend the SEP article on  Nothing as just a really entertaining read.
Examples of well known fairly modern philosophers making hay out of nothing are, Heidegger with his famous and often criticised dictum "the nothing itself noths [or nihilates]", and Sartre with his tome Being and Nothingness: An Essay on Phenomenological Ontology. Wittgenstein would probably make short work of the topic, along the lines of applying:

"In this sort of predicament, always ask yourself: How did we learn
the meaning of this word ("good", for instance)? From what sort of
examples? In what language-games? Then it will be easier for you to
see that the word must have a family of meanings."
-Wittgenstein, in Philosophical Investigations

So, looking at the use of the term nothing rather then going straight to applying the term without investigating it, so as to avoid:

“The confusions which occupy us arise when language is like an engine
idling, not when it is doing work.”
-ibid

A relevant example of this method is discussed here, the language-game of 'opposites' and the way we need more contextual clues than we may realise to interpret contrastives where we use the same word in multiple ways:
Life and Death as one and the same?
Also notable are challenges to the meaningfulness of nothing approached as a conceptual linguistic category, like
Philosophers or philosophical traditions that reject symbolic reasoning, and further discussion more directly relating these critiques to nothingness here Is there a name for the place in the human mind for *not* knowing - a place of curiosity, anger, insecurity, the void we grow in to as we develop?
I see the issues of 'nothing' as one of the classic problems of philosophy which we can 'cut our teeth' on, like the issues of solipsism. Which is to say, coming to strong conclusions or having strong opinions about nothing, is probably less useful than the philosophical exercise involved in thinking about how to organise our categories and framings, and how to grapple and solve apparent paradoxes generate by naive use of powerful words with many contexts, like nothing.
